# JS/TS how to iterate thru object array and change values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

consider the following array.

```
routingButtonsHighlighter = [
  {vehicle: true},
  {userAssignment: false},
  {relations: false}
];
```

What is the best way to build a function which can do the following goals?

1) will set all members to false
2) set chosen member to true ( passed as a parameter )

Comment: The variable `routingButtonsHighlighter` is an array, which contains individual objects. Is this written correctly? This way there can be multiple objects with the same keys and they would be set to true aswell.

Comment: @Mark, there's no JSON there.

Comment: @Andy you're right oops. I've been looking at too much JSON, I'll update the comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have an object with `vehicle`, `userAssignment` and `relations` as the keys. Updating their values would be as simple as `obj.vehicle = false` then.

Comment: Does every object in the array have exactly one property? Can more than object have the same property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent more specific requirements, this is a bit of a choose-your-own-adventure.

(Note: For brevity this code uses ES6 [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and ES2018 [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), all of which can be transpiled by TypeScript.)

### If each object has exactly one key

- #### ...and you want to mutate the original array and objects

```js
const objects = [ { vehicle: true }, { userAssignment: false }, { relations: false } ];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  for (let obj of objects) {
    const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
    obj[key] = key === selectedKey;
  }
  return objects;
}

selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment');
console.log(objects);
```

- #### ...and you want a new array of new objects

```js
const objects = [ { vehicle: true }, { userAssignment: false }, { relations: false } ];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  const newObjects = [];

  for (let obj of objects) {
    const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
    newObjects.push({ [key]: key === selectedKey });
  }
  
  return newObjects;
}

console.log(selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment'))
```

- #### ...but you really like functional style

```js
const objects = [ { vehicle: true }, { userAssignment: false }, { relations: false } ];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  return objects.map(obj => {
    const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
    return { [key]: key === selectedKey };
  });
}

console.log(selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment'))
```

### If the objects can have more than one key

- #### ...and you want to mutate the original array and objects

```js
const objects = [
  { vehicle: true, relations: false },
  { userAssignment: false, vehicle: true },
  { relations: false, userAssignment: false },
];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  for (let obj of objects) {
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      obj[key] = key === selectedKey;
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment');
console.log(objects);
```

- #### ...and you want a new array of new objects

```js
const objects = [
  { vehicle: true, relations: false },
  { userAssignment: false, vehicle: true },
  { relations: false, userAssignment: false },
];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  const newObjects = [];

  for (let obj of objects) {
    const newObj = {};
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      newObj[key] = key === selectedKey;
    }
    newObjects.push(newObj);
  }
  
  return newObjects;
}

console.log(selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment'))
```

- #### ...but you really like functional style

```js
const objects = [
  { vehicle: true, relations: false },
  { userAssignment: false, vehicle: true },
  { relations: false, userAssignment: false },
];

function selectKey(objects, selectedKey) {
  return objects.map(obj =>
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) =>
      ({ ...newObj, [key]: key === selectedKey }),
      {}
    )
  );
}

console.log(selectKey(objects, 'userAssignment'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), get the key using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), compare to the selected key, and set the value accordingly:

```js
const routingButtonsHighlighter = [{vehicle: true}, {userAssignment: false}, {relations: false}];

const select = (arr, selectedKey) =>
  arr.forEach((o) => {
    const key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    
    o[key] = key === selectedKey;
  });
  
select(routingButtonsHighlighter, 'userAssignment');

console.log(routingButtonsHighlighter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a method for something like this would be highly specialized, so to abstract it, I've decided to write it like this:

```
function arrayFlagSinglePropertyTrue(key, arrayofobjects) {

    for (let i in arrayofobjects) {

        let keys = Object.keys(arrayofobjects[i]);
        if (keys[0] == key) {
            arrayofobjects[i][keys[0]] = true;
        } else {
            arrayofobjects[i][keys[0]] = false;
        }

    }

    return arrayofobjects;

}

routingButtonsHighlighter = [
    {vehicle: true},
    {userAssignment: false},
    {relations: false}
];

console.log(arrayFlagSinglePropertyTrue("relations", routingButtonsHighlighter));
```

Although this will get what you require done, its highly specialized and only works if the objects in the array contain one property or at the very least the first property in the object itself is the one you want to set to flag.

---

**Edit:** Some advice:

Uniformity in lists helps avoid the issue you have. By structuring your objects with uniform property names and then acting on the values themselves, you no longer require the use of specialized functions or code in order to modify it. At this point you can rely on fundamental programming logic to change the properties efficiently.

If you get the list from some external source and have no control over it, then you may need to either reorganize it yourself. If you can't then making specialized functions/codes is your last resort.

If possible, take something like this:

```
routingButtonsHighlighter = [
    {vehicle: true},
    {userAssignment: false},
    {relations: false}
];
```

Organize it into something like this where the actual object properties are uniform:

```
let betterStructureObject = [
    { propertyName: "vehicle", status: true },
    { propertyName: "userAssignment", status: false },
    { propertyName: "vehicle", status: false },
]
```

So you can easily loop over it and not have to worry about writing specialized code.

```
for (let i in betterStructureObject) {

    if (betterStructureObject[i].propertyName == "vehicle")
         betterStructureObject[i].status = true;

    else betterStructureObject[i].status = false;

}
```

Comment: Hello Christopher, thank you for your answer. I marked another answer as a cool solution because it was a very exact answer to my question and it could be helpful for others but I personally chose your attitude and change array as you suggested. Thank you :)

Comment: Of course, I'm glad that my advice proved to be of use. JSON structures can be tricky so if there is one thing to take away, its learning to structure objects in a predictable way when possible.